# Android Navigation Drawer Material Design – Circle Image View Profile Picture

Tags: android, header, imageview

I implemented a simple navigation drawer in material design and put a profile picture in the header of that drawer. This profile picture is of the type: de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

When I run my app on the emulator and open the drawer up everything seems to freeze and move slowly as soon as the image is visible.
Should I try another way of rounding my ImageView or did I miss something?

(I followed this tutorial and looked over it 100 times: http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CircleImageView`. It's a good implementation and follows performance best practices.

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView